# Stock Browser in 4.4 KitKat Cannot do Uploads on Websites

Tags: android, mobile, file-upload, image-uploading, android-4.4-kitkat

It seems that the basic `<input type="file">` tag no longer functions when used inside the built-in Stock Android Web Browser on devices running **Android 4.4 KitKat**. The file selection modal simply does not appear.

I've tested this on actual devices and in emulators (local emulators and web-based emulator services like Browserstack) and none of them show me the file selection dialog when trying to select an item for upload.

It does work fine in Google Chrome on the same devices and it does seem to work in the next preview version of Android (L).

Is anyone else experiencing the same and have you found a workaround? This seems pretty basic but I'm not finding anyone talking about this issue.

Thank you!

Comment: There's an issue on this in http://b.android.com somewhere, as I recall seeing it.

Comment: I don't see any open issue about this. I'll have to open a ticket I guess. Do you have an Android 4.4 phone? Does it work for you? Here's a sample test page (doesn't upload but tests to see if the "Choose file for upload" dialog even opens): http://ramius.net/formtest